# Spring boot rest api returns 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have my main class like this:

```
package com.ratings.main;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

package com.ratings.controller;
@RestController
public class PollController {

    @Autowired
    Poll poll;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("home " + "HOME");
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

And pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ratings.main.App</groupId>
  <artifactId>Ratings</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Ratings</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.ratings.main.App</mainClass>
          <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

When I try `http://localhost:9090/` I get 404. Why is it not return string "Home"?

Comment: Can you add web mvc config class code ?

Comment: @drowny I didn't get you? What mvc config? Its a spring boot app

Comment: are these two classes in the same package?

Comment: @kingGarfield Yes

Comment: I'm also adding the webmvcconfiguration for other configurable param. So when app is started , is 9090 relevant port for inner tomcat server?  Or can you add your 404 error fully ?

Comment: Are you sure your port is correct? When you start application, you can see on which port the application started in logs

Comment: have you set the serverport to 9090? - standard-port is as far as i know 8080

Answer (score 0):

Your SpringBootApplication class is in the package:

```
package com.ratings.main;
```

And your controller in

```
package com.ratings.controller;
```

The controller must be in the same or below the SpringBootApplication.

So either move your SpringBootApplication to

```
com.ratings
```

or move the controller to

```
com.ratings.main.controller
```

Answer (score 0):

put your controller class in this package `com.ratings.main`.
`@SpringApplication` contains `@ComponentScan`. this annotation scans your beans and configurations from your main package and its subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication` package: `com.ratings.main;`

`@Controller` package:  `com.ratings.controller;`

The `controller class` must be in the same or below the main class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. You can solve this with adding example package like this ;
`com.ratings.main.*;`  same order or below.

On the other hand you can use @ComponentScan for your controller packages.

```
@ComponentScan(value = {"your.controller.package"})
```

`@SpringBootApplication` already has this tag but it's scanning only same order and below.